# Pointer parameter warning

Tags: c, pointers

**I have following error:**

> GOL.c:49: warning: conflicting types for ‘calculatePos’

**Here is code related to that matter:**

```
void calculatePos(int **board, int x, int y) {
...
...
}

void nextGeneration(int **board) {
    for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<col; j++) {
            calculatePos(board, i, j);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
...
nextGeneration(board);
...
}
```

**I have warning on following line:**

> void calculatePos(int **board, int x, int y) {

How can I fix error?

Comment: look at your prototype of `calculatePos()`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: In my view, it is worth enforcing that functions are fully declared before use.  I routinely use `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition …` for compiling.  It prevents problems.

Answer (score 0):

After I declare a prototype for `calculatePos()`, the warning has gone.

Comment: @Marievi-- it is acceptable to self-answer. This seems like a border case, but I think that it qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @DavidBowling then you should also accept it, so that the question will appear as resolved.